# Composer diagnose and install error

Tags: php, git, ssl, composer-php

If I run "composer diagnose" it gaves me a FAIL message when checking github.com rate limit:

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

I'm NOT behind a proxy or firewall and I CAN download everything from HTTP or HTTPS. I've tried to change my cacert.pem and everything more. But nothing can fix it.

When I try to install a package an error occurs too:

```
sudo composer require cocur/slugify
Using version ^2.0 for cocur/slugify
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing cocur/slugify (v2.0)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download cocur/slugify from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/cocur/slugify/zipball/912bf41f940f9a4e38ff1284b1841eaa71911d7f" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing cocur/slugify (v2.0)
    Cloning 912bf41f940f9a4e38ff1284b1841eaa71911d7f
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                               
  Failed to clone https://github.com/cocur/slugify.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.                                                         
  - https://github.com/cocur/slugify.git                                                                                                           
    Cloning into '/home/user/temp/vendor/cocur/slugify'...                                                                                         
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cocur/slugify.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.  
  - git@github.com:cocur/slugify.git                                                                                                               
    Cloning into '/home/user/temp/vendor/cocur/slugify'...                                                                                         
    Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.                                                       
    Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                 
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                  

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                            
    and the repository exists.                                                                                                                     


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Did you generate an OAuth token like suggested in https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens ? Have you got openssl php extension installed?